# Issues with recursive backtracking

Tags: java, algorithm, sudoku

I am trying to implement a backtracking algorithm in Java, to solve a sudoku problem.

I'm 95% sure the problem is in solve method, but I included the two accesory methods in case.

Some of the strange-ish things I'm doing are just due to requirements/convenience, like the hard-coded initial values for the puzzle. I'm sure the issue lies near the bottom of my solve method, but I cannot figure it out...

My current problem is this: after working on the first row, and finding a potentially valid permutation of values, my program simply gives up. If I uncomment the line that prints "ROW IS DONE," it'll print that after ONE row, and no more output is given. Why is it giving up after the first row? Is there anything else about my implementation I should be worried about

EDIT: I made a lot of changes. It is getting very close. If I print when EXHAUST is true, I get a puzzle that has every row solved except the last one. It looks like it is undoing everything after it's solved/nearly solved it. I get the feeling that it might already reach  point where the puzzle is fully solved, but I'm not passing back TRUE at the right time... What am I doing wrong now?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Model
{
    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    int[][] grid = 
            {
              {5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0},
              {6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0},
              {0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0},
              {8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3},
              {4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1},
              {7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6},
              {0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0},
              {0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5},
              {0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9}
            };

    /**
     * Method solve
     * 
     * Uses a backtracking algorithm to solve the puzzle.
     */
    public boolean solve(int row, int col) //mutator
    {   
        if(exhaust(row,col)) {printGrid(); return true;}
        int rownext = row;
        int colnext = col+1;
        if(colnext>8)
        {
            colnext = 0;
            rownext++;
        }           
        if(grid[row][col] != 0) solve(rownext,colnext);
        else //is == 0
        {
            for(int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
            {   
                if(!conflict(row,col,num)) //try a non-conflicting number   
                {
                    grid[row][col] = num;
                    if(solve(rownext,colnext)) return true;                     
                    grid[row][col] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;       

    }
    /**
     * Method exhaust
     * 
     * Iteratively searches the rest of the puzzle for empty space
     * using the parameters as the starting point.
     *
     * @return true if no 0's are found
     * @return false if a 0 is found
     */
    public boolean exhaust(int row, int col)
    {
        for(int i = row; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            for(int j = col; j <= 8; j++)
            {
                if(grid[i][j] == 0) return false;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Exhausted.\n");
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Method conflict
     * 
     * Checks if the choice in question is valid by looking to see
     * if the choice has already been made in the same row or col,
     * or block. 
     *
     * @return true if there IS a conflict
     * @return false if there is NOT a conflict
     */
    public boolean conflict(int row, int col, int num)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 8; j++)
        {
            if(grid[row][j] == num) {
                return true;
            }
        }   
        for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            if(grid[i][col] == num) {
                return true;
            }
        }           

        int rowstart = 0;
        if(row>=3) rowstart = 3;
        if(row>=6) rowstart = 6;

        int colstart = 0;
        if(col>=3) colstart = 3;
        if(col>=6) colstart = 6;                    

        for(int r = rowstart; r <= (rowstart + 2); r++)
        {
            for(int c = colstart; c <= (colstart + 2); c++)
            {
                if(grid[r][c] == num) {
                    return true;
                }   
            }   
        }       
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Eclipse or other high-level IDE start working with debugger.  You can go step by step and see where your program leads you.

Comment: @PM77-1 I tried setting up eclipse on my machine, but the debugger refused to actually run. I think last time I used eclipse was when I was using windows, and that went fine, but it seems like so much trouble to get it working on *nix...

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you're moving forward smoothly, row by row, and haven't backtracked.  Your next position is `solve(1,1);`.  Pay attention to rownext as you trace through your code.  You should see the problem quickly.  If you aren't backtracking, rownext should hold its value of at least 1.

Comment: You pointed out the problem he noticed, but there's also a problem with `exhaust()`. I'm also not sure the backtracking works...

**edit** I *think* the backtracking does work, but I'm not sure why you wouldn't just return a `boolean` to short circuit some of that logic?

Comment: You mean, rewrite solve as boolean method? I only wrote it as void because that is what the psuedo-code provided by my professor suggested. I thought it'd be easier that way, but maybe not.

Comment: I know a better question that might help me. I've thought about how backtracking needs to work... should exhaust only check to see if there are more spaces to attempt, or should it validate every decision made so far? I was thinking about the very last step, where I have a filled-in puzzle, and I'm not sure how/where to check all the numbers to see if everything actually turned out OK, or if that's supposed to happen ONLY AS the puzzle is being solved...

EDIT: nevermind, I should probably write a more complete "conflict" method, right?

Comment: Your test for when the board is exhausted could occur immediately after `rownext++`, and need only check for rownext==9.  It would save you some unnecessary processing.

Comment: Assuming someone enters a puzzle with more than one solution, is your goal to find all possible solutions or just find one viable solution and stop?

Comment: @phatfingers Find one viable solution. In fact, the solution was provided, because this is not supposed to be the focus of the exercise..

Comment: I'm not trying to distract you.  You have a line of code, `if(grid[row][col] != 0) solve(rownext,colnext);`.  If `solve(rownext,colnext)` returns true, your code will keep on trying to solve even if a prior solution was found.

Comment: @phatfingers I followed your suggestion. if(rownext==9) {printGrid(); return true;} The printGrid() call will print a solution, but after, it looks like my solver is still backtracking completely to the original state!

Comment: @phatfingers Right, then the question for me is, "how do I continue searching if I still have yet to find a solution, but not after I find one?" Without this line, it looked like my code would modify some of the given values..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28169/discussion-between-grinreaper-and-phatfingers)